# What Scope are Webpack'd CONST in

Tags: javascript, webpack, scope

We have Webpack setup to let us have ES6 style code for a project that needs to transpile down to ES5 so IE11 can run it (project requirement for IE - now ours.)

Even though this is using Vue.js, AFAIK, that is NOT the issue here.  It's ***where are `export` values going***.

The following code works when I am NOT using Webpack:

***Working.cshtml***

```
<div id="app">
  ...
</div>

var vm = new Vue({
  data: {
    ...
  },
  methods: {
    ...
  }
});

$(function () {
  //vm.$mount('#app'); // This works
  var testName = "vm";
  window[testName].$mount("#app"); // This also works
});
```

We have to use the `$mount` way (as opposed to having an `el: "$app"` property because we are Webpacking many files into one.  Also, that is where the `testName` variable comes into play.  I will read that true value from a hidden field as seen below.

Here is what the page needs to actually have and is not working:

***TestPortable.js***

```
const testPortable = new Vue({
  data: {
    ...
  },
  methods: {
    ...
  },
  created: function () {
    console.log(" * Created testPortable"); // This shows
  },
  mounted: function () {
    console.log(" * Mounted testPortable"); // Never gets here
  }
});

export default testPortable;
```

Here is the file with the HTML markup on it that needs to find the `testPortable` variable.

***Current.cshml***

```
<input type="hidden" id="hdnTestName" value="testPortable" />
<div id="app">
  ...
</div>

<script>
$(function () {
  console.log("Document is Ready");
  var TestName = document.getElementById("hdnTestName").value; // TestName === "testPortable"
  console.log("  Test Name: " + TestName);             // testPortable
  console.log("  on window: " + window[TestName]);     // undefined
  console.log("  on document: " + document[TestName]); // undefined
  console.log("  on this: " + this[TestName]);         // undefined
  console.log("  on force: " + window.testPortable);   // undefined
  window[TestName].$mount("#app");                     // Cannot read property '$mount' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property '$mount' of undefined
  console.log("  Post Mount Call");                    // Never gets here
});
</script>
```

So, as the question asks, where the heck is the `testPortable` `const` at?  I looked in the rendered `app.js` file and do see that it is in there.

***app.js***

```
...
(function (module, exports, __webpack_require__) {
  "use strict";
  var _vue = __webpack_require__(/*! vue */ "./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.js");
  var _vue2 = _interopRequireDefault(_vue);

  var testPortable = new _vue2.default({
    ...
  });
});
...
```

I am so close to having this working but can't get past this `scope` issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `webpack.config.js`, under `output`, you can add the `libraryTarget` option with a `'window'` value  - along with `library` to set the name, e.g. `library: '[name]'` *(which will use the entry/bundle name)*:

```
output: {
    library: '[name]',
    libraryTarget: 'window'
}
```

Assuming your class/module is exported *(using your 'testPortable' as an example)*:

```
export const testPortable = new Vue({})
```

and your entry/bundle name is `app`, you should then be able to access it using `window.app.testPortable` or `window.app['testPortable']`

Note: You'll need to be sure the bundle has first been loaded using `DOMContentLoaded` / `$(document).ready()`

You may want to further review Webpack's documentation on output options: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#output-library